# Can't invite other users via their ID using /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/invite

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Hello we are attempting to invite people (assign permissions for driveItems), that are members of the directory (tenant) using their IDs as returned by the `/users` endpoint. But unfortunately this results in the following error: `One of the provided recipients could not be found`.

The body of a request:

```
{'recipients': [{'objectId': u'21509bcb-d48c-4d66-8222-9da2c5ed2f7c'}],
 'requireSignIn': True,
 'roles': ['read'],
 'sendInvitation': True}
```

The response:

```
{u'error': {u'code': u'itemNotFound',
            u'innerError': {u'date': u'2018-03-09T02:42:46',
                            u'request-id': u'a0f919f2-02f6-4a95-ac60-18b8a3522ba2'},
            u'message': u'One of the provided recipients could not be found'}
```

Using a users email works but the weird thing about that is, when we retrieve the driveItem's permissions after the invite the permission for that user doesn't contain the email BUT the ID with which we tried initially to invite him (and that fails).

Are the IDs, that must be specified for `objectId`, different or is this an internal issues?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Is this still an issue? So far we still use the workaround by using the user's UPN. Might check later if it's now possible to use the UID. Because the Graph API is always changing and suddenly things work.